# Facebook Auth with AngularJS and Django REST Framework

Tags: facebook, angularjs, django-rest-framework, python-social-auth

I am developing a SPA application with [AngularJS](http://angularjs.org/) which uses [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) backend for the server. The way that I communicate with the server from the SPA is with [django-rest-framework](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework). So now I want to make authentication with facebook (google and twitter too) and I read a lot on this topic and found [OAuth.io](https://oauth.io/) which is making the authetication on the client SPA side and [python-social-auth](https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth) which is doing the same thing but on the server side.

So currently I have only the client auth, my app is connecting to facebook (with OAuth.io) and login successfully. This process is returning access_token and then I am making a request to my API which have to login this user or create account for this user by given token and this part is not working. So I am not sure where I am wrong, maybe because there isn't a full tutorial about using python-social-auth so maybe I am missing something or.. I don't know..

So some code of this what I have:

On the SPA side: This is the connection with OAuth.io and is working because I am getting the access token. Then I have to make a request to my rest API. backend is 'facebook', 'google' or 'twitter'

```
OAuth.initialize('my-auth-code-for-oauthio');
OAuth.popup(backend, function(error, result) {
    //handle error with error
    //use result.access_token in your API request

    var token = 'Token ' + result.access_token;
    var loginPromise = $http({
         method:'POST', 
         url: 'api-token/login/' + backend + '/', 
         headers: {'Authorization': token}});

         loginPromise.success(function () {
             console.log('Succeess');
         });
         loginPromise.error(function (result) {
             console.log('error');
         });
});
```

On the server in my settings.py I have added social plugin to the installed apps, template context preprocessors, some auth backends and that is my file:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    ...,
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'api',
    'social.apps.django_app.default',
    'social'
)
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = ("django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
                               "django.core.context_processors.debug",
                               "django.core.context_processors.i18n",
                               "django.core.context_processors.media",
                               "django.core.context_processors.static",
                               "django.core.context_processors.request",
                               "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
                               'social.apps.django_app.context_processors.backends',
                               'social.apps.django_app.context_processors.login_redirect',)

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    )
}

SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_KEY = 'key'
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SECRET = 'secret'
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SCOPE = ['email']

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
      'social.backends.open_id.OpenIdAuth',
      'social.backends.facebook.FacebookOAuth2',
      'social.backends.facebook.FacebookAppOAuth',
      'social.backends.google.GoogleOpenId',
      'social.backends.google.GoogleOAuth2',
      'social.backends.google.GoogleOAuth',
      'social.backends.twitter.TwitterOAuth',
      'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
  )
```

In my views.py of the API I have the following (I found it [here](http://blog.wizer.fr/2013/11/angularjs-facebook-with-a-django-rest-api/)):

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group
from rest_framework import viewsets, generics
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import authentication, permissions, parsers, renderers
from rest_framework.authtoken.serializers import AuthTokenSerializer
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view, throttle_classes
from social.apps.django_app.utils import strategy
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated, IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly

from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token

class ObtainAuthToken(APIView):
    throttle_classes = ()
    permission_classes = ()
    parser_classes = (parsers.FormParser, parsers.MultiPartParser, parsers.JSONParser,)
    renderer_classes = (renderers.JSONRenderer,)
    serializer_class = AuthTokenSerializer
    model = Token

    # Accept backend as a parameter and 'auth' for a login / pass
    def post(self, request, backend):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.DATA)

        if backend == 'auth':
            if serializer.is_valid():
                token, created = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=serializer.object['user'])
                return Response({'token': token.key})
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

        else:
            # Here we call PSA to authenticate like we would if we used PSA on server side.
            user = register_by_access_token(request, backend)

            # If user is active we get or create the REST token and send it back with user data
            if user and user.is_active:
                token, created = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
                return Response({'id': user.id , 'name': user.username, 'userRole': 'user','token': token.key})

@strategy()
def register_by_access_token(request, backend):
    backend = request.strategy.backend
    user = request.user
    user = backend._do_auth(
        access_token=request.GET.get('access_token'),
        user=user.is_authenticated() and user or None
    )
    return user
```

And finally I have these routes in urls.py:

```
...
url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
url(r'^api-token-auth/', 'rest_framework.authtoken.views.obtain_auth_token'),
url(r'^api-token/login/(?P<backend>[^/]+)/$', views.ObtainAuthToken.as_view()),
url(r'^register/(?P<backend>[^/]+)/', views.register_by_access_token),
...
```

Everytime when I try to do auth, OAuth.io is working and the rqest to api returns

> detail: "Invalid token"

I think that I missed something in the configuration of python-social-auth or I am doing everything wrong. So I will be glad if anyone has some ideas and want to help :)

Comment: Looks like you are passing the token in a header, but looking for it on `request.GET` on `register_by_access_token`.

Comment: I see that but this was the example [here](http://blog.wizer.fr/2013/11/angularjs-facebook-with-a-django-rest-api/) but I cannot understand how works python-social-auth because there isn't exmples how to use it. So maybe I won't have social auth.. thanks :)

Comment: you could try the code in this page: http://blog.wizer.fr/2013/11/angularjs-facebook-with-a-django-rest-api/
which takes the token from the header.

Comment: yea i know that probably it's to late, but have you solved this problem? I've only managed to get unautorized request code Status Code:401 UNAUTHORIZED

Comment: @valkirilov, any idea how will we integrate openid connect ?

Answer (score 7):

Add the following line to your ObtainAuthToken class

```
authentication_classes = ()
```

and your error {"detail": "Invalid token"} will go away.

**Here's why...**

Your request contains the following header

```
Authorization: Token yourAccessToken
```

yet you have defined rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication in DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES.

Based on this Django thinks you want to perform token authentication as you have passed a Token in.  It fails because this is an access token for facebook and doesn't exist in your django *_token database, hence the invalid token error.  In your case all you need to do is tell Django not to use TokenAuthentication for this view.

**FYI**

Keep in mind you may encounter further errors as your code execution was halted before the post method of ObtainAuthToken executed.  Personally when trying to step through your code I got the error

```
'DjangoStrategy' object has no attribute 'backend'
```

on

```
backend = request.strategy.backend
```

and resolved it by changing to

```
uri = ''
strategy = load_strategy(request)
backend = load_backend(strategy, backend, uri)
```

Additionally you should update your you register_by_access_token function as it doesn't line up with the working code from the blog you referenced.  The blog author posted his latest code [here](https://gist.github.com/jproby/8944448).  Your version doesn't pull the token out of the auth header which is required if you want to use it to auth with a third party like facebook.

Comment: Thank you. 'DjangoStrategy' object has no attribute 'backend' tip helped a lot

Answer (score 5):

Yea. Solved. The settings are not right and you need to add permissions.

```
 REST_FRAMEWORK = {
     # Use hyperlinked styles by default.
     # Only used if the `serializer_class` attribute is not set on a view.
     'DEFAULT_MODEL_SERIALIZER_CLASS':
         'rest_framework.serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer',

     # Use Django's standard `django.contrib.auth` permissions,
     # or allow read-only access for unauthenticated users.
     'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
         'rest_framework.permissions.DjangoModelPermissionsOrAnonReadOnly'
     ]
 }
```

and some info about pipeline:

```
 SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE = (
     'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_details',
     'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_uid',
     'social.pipeline.social_auth.auth_allowed',
     'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_user',
     'social.pipeline.user.get_username',
     'social.pipeline.social_auth.associate_by_email',
     'social.pipeline.user.create_user',
     'social.pipeline.social_auth.associate_user',
     'social.pipeline.social_auth.load_extra_data',
     'social.pipeline.user.user_details'
 )
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm using tools just like you, but I provide my login/register/.... with 
[`django-allauth`](http://django-allauth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) package, and then use [`django-rest-auth`](http://django-rest-auth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) for API handling.

You just need follow the installation instruction, then use them for your rest APIs.

Adding `allauth` and `rest-auth` to your INSTALLED_APPS:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...,
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'rest_auth'
    ...,
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'rest_auth.registration',
    ...,
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.facebook',
)
```

Then add your custom urls:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ...,
    (r'^auth/', include('rest_auth.urls')),
    (r'^auth/registration/', include('rest_auth.registration.urls'))
)
```

Finally, add this line:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    ...,
    'allauth.account.context_processors.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount.context_processors.socialaccount',
    ...
)
```

These two packages works like a charm, and you don't need to have concern about any type of login.registration, because `allauth` package handles both django model login and oAuth login.

I hope it helps

Comment: It's been a while, this still is a problem!
I found django-rest-auth to be better than the other options mentioned in this thread.